# Angular join results of two subscribes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two subscribes in my ngOnInit and I want to join the results of this two into one string.

## Code

```
val:string = ''
col: string = ''

ngOnInit() {
    this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
      console.log('newValue', newValue)
      if(newValue != null){
        this.val = newValue;
      }
    });

    this.globalSearchService.searchColumn.subscribe((column: string) => {
      console.log('column', column)
      if(column != null){
        this.col = column;
      }
    });

    // from here down, never fire!
    console.log('val', this.val)
    console.log('col', this.col)

    if(this.col != '' && this.val != '') {
      this.inputValue.push(this.col + ' | ' +this.val);
    }
}
```

**any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subscribe()` does not happen on init, you define it on init and it will happen when the data arrived. How about:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
      if(newValue){
        this.val = newValue;
        this.tryJoinValues();
      }
    });

    this.globalSearchService.searchColumn.subscribe((column: string) => {
      if(column){
        this.col = column;
        this.tryJoinValues();
      }
    });
}

tryJoinValues(){
    if(this.col && this.val) {
      this.inputValue.push(this.col + ' | ' +this.val);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this does a nice job but there is an issue, when second time data arrives it will mix up with first values therefore it return extra data in `this.inputValue` and obviously wrong data.

Comment: i fixed it by adding this `this.col = ''
      this.val = ''` after `this.inputValue.push(this.col + ' | ' +this.val);`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using higher order 'rxjs' operators. This would include **forkJoin** and **combineLatest** etc.

Below is an approach using **combineLatest**. remember to include `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'`

```typescript
val:string = ''
col: string = ''

ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest([this.globalSearchService.searchTerm, this.globalSearchService.searchColumn]).pipe(
  tap(([val, col]) => {
    if(val != null){
        this.val = val;
      }
    if(col != null){
        this.col = col;
      }
    if(this.col != '' && this.val != '') {
      this.inputValue.push(this.col + ' | ' +this.val);
    }
  })
).subscribe()
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's already solved but I'll definitely try your answer as well (at least I learn more :D)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `searchTerm` and `searchColumn` will update in tandem with one another, you should use the [zip](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-zip) function:

You do not need to store the individual values in `this.val` or `this.col`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    zip(
       this.globalSearchService.searchColumn,
       this.globalSearchService.searchTerm
    ).pipe(
        map((results:string[]) => `${results[0]} | ${results[1]}`)
    ).subscribe(
       (concatenatedString) => this.inputValue.push(concatenatedString) 
    );

}
```

Comment: why here has 2 `this.globalSearchService.searchColumn` `this.globalSearchService.searchTerm` based on your code it seems there is no need of `.subscribe(` part because no where in zip you haven't used `this.col` or `this.val`

Comment: @mafortis - Do you need the members `this.val` or `this.col` for any other reason? If it's just to create the concatenated string, then you don't need them.

Comment: no that was the only reason of creating them.

Comment: @mafortis - In that case, you can get rid of the first two subscribes, and just have the `zip` call. I'll change the code to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) for this. If you are familiar with Promises, this is very similar to `Promise.all()`. The `forkJoin()` operator allows us to take a list of Observables and execute them in parallel.

Once every Observable in the list emits a value, the forkJoin will emit a single Observable value containing a list of all the resolved values from the Observables. So your code will look like this after using forkJoin.

```
let searchTerm = this.globalSearchService.searchTerm;
let searchColumn = this.globalSearchService.searchColumn;

forkJoin([searchTerm , searchColumn ]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] is our searchColumn 
  // results[1] is our searchColumn 
  let val  = results[0];
  let col = results[1];
  if(val != null){
    this.val = val;
  }
  if(col != null){
    this.col = col;
  }
  if(this.col != '' && this.val != '') {
    this.inputValue.push(this.col + ' | ' +this.val);
  }
});
```